# Pure pandas implementation of TF-IDF

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm wondering why my Pandas implementation of TF-IDF shows slightly different results than the sklearn implementation.

Here's my implementation:

```
text = ["aa bb cc dd ee", "bb cc dd dd"]

terms = [Counter(t.split(' ')) for t in text]
tf = pd.DataFrame(terms)
tf = tf.fillna(0)

num_docs = len(text)
idf = np.log(num_docs / tf[tf >= 1].count()) + 1 

tf_idf = tf * idf

norm = np.sqrt((tf_idf ** 2).sum(axis=1))
norm_tf_idf = tf_idf.div(norm, axis=0)

>>> norm_tf_idf
         aa        bb        cc        dd        ee
0  0.572929  0.338381  0.338381  0.338381  0.572929
1  0.000000  0.408248  0.408248  0.816497  0.000000
```

However if I use sklearn:

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, stop_words=None, sublinear_tf=True)
x = tf.fit_transform(text)

sk = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray())
sk.columns = tf.get_feature_names()
sk

>>> sk
         aa        bb        cc        dd        ee
0  0.572929  0.338381  0.338381  0.338381  0.572929
1  0.000000  0.453295  0.453295  0.767495  0.000000
```

Or if we subtract them:

```
>>> norm_tf_idf - sk
    aa        bb        cc        dd   ee
0  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
1  0.0 -0.045046 -0.045046  0.049002  0.0
```

---

Edit:

I found out the sklearn idf is not exactly the same as my idf, but we can attribute this to floating point precision I think:

```
sklearn idf: [1.69314718 1.         1.         1.         1.69314718]
my idf:      [1.693147   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.693147]
```

And even if I use the sklearn idf, I still get different results.

Furthermore, if I don't normalize and use the sklearn idf values only the TF-IDF for `dd` of the second document differs:

```
sk_tfv = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, stop_words=None, token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", sublinear_tf=True, norm=None)
x = sk_tf.fit_transform(text)
sk_tf_idf = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray())
...
idf = sk_tfv.idf_
tf_idf = tf * idf


>>> tf_idf - sk_tf_idf
     aa  bb  cc       dd     ee
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.306853    0.0
```

This means either two things:
1. The problem is my TF. However this is easily checkable and doesn't seems to be the case. Or,
2. sklearn doesn't just do `TF * IDF`, but does something more, which I have to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid. After diving in the sklearn source, I noticed the `sublinear_tf` parameter. With this parameter set to True the term frequency is replaced by `log(TF) + 1` and it just happend to be that I set this parameter to `True` :)

To implement sublinear TF in pandas this should work:

```
tf[tf > 0]  = np.log(tf[tf > 0] ) + 1
```